# Run job unless all changed files end in .md

Tags: gitlab-ci

The docs cover how to run a job if any file matching `*.md` has changed, or to never run a job if a file matching `*.md` is changed. But these seem far less useful than the use case in the title: run the (say, test) job unless *all* changed files match `*.md`.

Is it supported?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a glob pattern that will match all *non-markdown* files to control when the job (or pipeline with `workflow:rules:`) using rules:

```yaml
myjob:
  rules:
    # only run when changes include non-markdown files.
    - changes:
        - "**/{*[^.]md*,*.[^m]*,*.m,*.m[^d]*,*.md?*,*[^d]}"
```

You can [test this glob](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=%2A%2A%2F%7B%2A%5B%5E.%5Dmd%2A%2C%2A.%5B%5Em%5D%2A%2C%2A.m%2C%2A.m%5B%5Ed%5D%2A%2C%2A.md%3F%2A%2C%2A%5B%5Ed%5D%7D&matches=false&options=dot%3Atrue&tests=README.md&tests=docs%2Fapi.md&tests=%2Fhello%2Fworld.js&tests=.gitlab-ci.yml) and see that it will match on anything *except* `.md` files.